# C++20 solutions for temporary ownership of resources

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, c++20

I have a resource managed by an external system with the following API:

```
 struct api { 
   resource* acquire();
   void release(resource*);
 };
```

My code requires to temporarily share one of these resources across multiple threads, so I need to put the resource in a `shared_ptr` to get a reference count:

```
std::shared_ptr<resource> res = m_api.acquire();
```

This API requires the resources being freed from the same thread in which they were acquired.

My problem is giving it back when all the threads are done with that resource, as `std::shared_ptr` does not have `release`.

1/ I cannot just let the pointers wither on their own when they aren't used as I don't know which thread will be the last if I do that (and it needs to be the main thread).

2/ I need to add a custom deleter which stores a `api*`, which is too costly in this case - I can already barely afford a "simple" `std::shared_ptr` with its default deleter.

What are my solutions, if possible without having to reimplement an atomic reference count myself ?

Comment: How is the main thread going to know when to release the resource? Should it block until all pointers die, or periodically check if they died?

Comment: There are periodic checks

Comment: What about adding a new layer? A thread that does all the communication with the API, all the acquires, and wraps these resources in objects; the other threads request a shared pointer to those "wrap objects" to this "resource manager" thread; the destructor of the "wrap object" releases the resource, always from the same thread.

Comment: You can make an aliasing `std::shared_ptr` that points to the resource but owns a different object whose destructor can be used to notify the main thread to actually release the resource. See constructor #8 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Comment: oh, that is a very interesting use of the aliasing ctor indeed, I'm going to try that.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier I think it may be even easier to just pass a custom deleter whose job is to notify the main thread. Depending on how the notification system is implemented.